# Alder Lake 12 gen laptop 400 Mhz

Tags: 20.04, cpu, frequency

laptop MSI gs66 12700, ubuntu 20.04, kernel: 5.17.0-2.3-liquorix-amd64

after power disconnect CPU down to 400 Mhz and not recovering after power connect.
in result system working slow, only reset helping.
same drop to 400 Mhz happening time to time with heavy load (run VSCode with big AOSP project, continuous disk read-write in hundreds gigabytes)

"with stress" --cpu 20 got freqs:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'MHz'

cpu MHz         : 399.999
cpu MHz         : 400.000
cpu MHz         : 399.999
cpu MHz         : 399.999
cpu MHz         : 399.999
cpu MHz         : 399.999
cpu MHz         : 399.999
cpu MHz         : 400.000
cpu MHz         : 400.000
cpu MHz         : 399.999
cpu MHz         : 400.000
cpu MHz         : 399.999
cpu MHz         : 400.000
cpu MHz         : 399.999
cpu MHz         : 399.999
cpu MHz         : 399.999
cpu MHz         : 2881.999
cpu MHz         : 2881.999
cpu MHz         : 2881.998
cpu MHz         : 2881.997
```

Comment: Hello. Are you sure this is a supported kernel for your version of Ubuntu?

Comment: try reverting to your previous kernel version, boot your laptop, hold down shift key, choose the previous kernel. if this solves your problem, take steps to rectify the situation permanently

Comment: You have 4 CPUs at higher frequency. The new processor have performance cores and efficient cores. I suspect you are power limit throttling.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-12700H. All core were blocked at 400Mhz and I couldn't figure why until I unplugged my smartphone from the charger which was also powering the laptop through USB-C.

It was in fact due to the lack of available power from the USB-C (min 65W needed), the laptop was going into a low power mode even as the battery was full.

The solution is to use a charger which deliver the minimum amount of power needed by the device when running.

Regards,

Comment: Not sure how that is an answer. Would the charger it came with not have the correct power?